# bash moving hidden files, reset dotglob?

Tags: bash, mv, dot-files

I wanted to move all files, including starting with dot (hidden) and folders (recursively).

So I used the following commands

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
mv ~/public/* ~/public_html/
```

and it worked.

But do I need to reset anything after doing `shopt -s dotglob nullglob`? Doesn't it change how commands like `mv` operate? Because I would like it changed back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you would have to unset those options (with `shopt -u nullglob dotglob`) afterwards if you wanted the default globbing behaviour back in the current shell.

You could just do

```
mv ~/public/* ~/public/.* ~/public_html/
```

That would still generate an error without `nullglob` set if one of the patterns didn't match anything, obviously, but would work without having to set either option. It would probably also say something about failing to rename `.` since it's a directory, but that too isn't stopping it from moving the files.

A better option may be to use `rsync` locally:

```
rsync -av ~/public/ ~/public_html/
```

and then delete `~/public`.

Comment: `~/public/*` is a subset of `~/public/.*`, so you only need to do `mv ~/public/.* ~/public_html/`

Comment: @pileofrogs That's simply not true. Try running `echo .*` in your home directory. Compare with `echo *`.

Comment: Huh.  I ran `ls .*` before posting and saw several files without a `.` at the beginning.  Will investigate further.

Comment: @pileofrogs Yes, those would be files in sub-directories. The directories themselves will have a `.` in the start of their names.

Comment: You sir are correct!  I just tried it with a few dummy files and mv behaves as you describe.  I tip my hat to you, sir!

Comment: @pileofrogs You are most gracious.

Comment: Even weirder!  I run `ls .*` and it shows me the contents of the parent directory, presumably because `..` is matched by `.*`  Perhaps `mv` and `echo` have some kind of resistance to `..` that I wasn't aware of.  I'll have to go read up.  Thank you again! @Kusalananda

Comment: @pileofrogs Try again with `set -x` enabled. It will show you what gets executed. `echo .*` _should_ output `.` and `..` and any other name matching that pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Simply unset them:

```
shopt -u dotglob nullglob
```

don_crissti makes a good point that I'll elaborate on. It's not clear from the question if either dotglob or nullglob were *already* set before running `shopt -s` to set them. Thus, blindly un-setting them may not be the proper *reset* to do. Setting them in a subshell would leave the current shell's settings unchanged:

```
( shopt -s dotglob nullglob; mv ~/public/* ~/public_html/ )
```

Comment: `nullglob` makes little since here though. `failglob` would make more sense, but the default would work as well, you'd just get an error from `mv` about not being able to move the `*` file instead of the shell failing to match `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script that reset the option:

```bsh
shopt -q dotglob && SHOPT_DOTGLOBAL=true || SHOPT_DOTGLOBAL=false
shopt -s dotglob # include hidden file
echo *
"$SHOPT_DOTGLOBAL" || shopt -u dotglob
```

Another way is to use `shopt -p` that prints commands:

```bsh
SHOPT_DOTGLOBAL_RESET=$(shopt -p dotglob) || true
shopt -s dotglob # include hidden file
echo *
eval "${SHOPT_DOTGLOBAL_RESET}"
```

(`shopt -p dotglob` would return with a non-zero exit status if the option was not set which would cause the shell to exit if the `errexit` option was on, hence the `|| true` to guard against it).

Answer (score 0):

Any changes made by shopt will only affect the shell you're running when you run the command.  IE once you close that shell, the change is gone.  So, unless you like to keep one shell open for a long time (which some do, using `screen` or similar) you don't need to worry about it.

Personally, I use rsync as suggested by @Kusalananda